# AWS SQS and SQS DLQs are the fail safe. What if the SQS Service Fails?

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, amazon-sqs, resiliency, dlq

I use SQS and SQS based DLQs a lot to have resiliency in my application architecture.
What is the best way to implement a DLQ when AWS SQS Service is not available and adding the event to SQS fails?

Comment: Amazon SQS is a regional-based service that operates across multiple Availability Zones and data centers in the region. If you are concerned about it being unavailable, you could consider a **multi-region** approach. I can't recall a time when Amazon SQS has failed, so you might want to concentrate your efforts on resiliency for your apps in case of a problem with Compute services.